# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, cryptography, pycrypto, pycryptodome, python-3.11

im install pycryto in python 3.11.3 and that was the error(cryptography is installed successfully):

```
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [179 lines of output]

      ...
  
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.33.31629\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycrypto, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How can i fix that and install Crypto(pycrypo)?
im just wirting for that:"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
"; XD

THX :)

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, while implementing ECC, just installed

pip uninstall pycrypto

pip install pycryptodome

worked fine for me